# Changing Field Visibility with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I have the same problem stated here:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/98493

When I set the visibility of a field to HIDDEN, the field won't hide:

```
l = arcpy.mapping.Layer("myLayer")
desc = arcpy.Describe(l)
finfo = desc.fieldInfo
index = 0
finfo.setVisible(index,"HIDDEN")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fieldInfo object is used to modify field properties when creating a new layer, e.g. with the Make Feature Layer tool. You can't use it to change directly your layer properties.

Comment: Thanks. you are right. The fieldInfo property of the layer is readonly.